# Set the font only for one letter in the entire document

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-fonts

While writing the paper, the letter `\xi` appear strangely as in the first figure.

[image]

What I wanted is [image]

Can anyone help how can I declare as I want globally ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which math font do you employ at present?

Comment: mathpazo  is set by the journal. I just wanted to change it only for one symbol.

Comment: Hmm... if that is the font set by the journal, they'll probably use it in production. So you can change it locally, but there is a high probability that they would use their choice (this is LaTeX: you concentrate on the content and the publisher on the look).

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't feel good to answer my own question, I solved it by declaring a new font as

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{CMletters}{"18}
```

Thanks

Comment: Self-answers are perfectly acceptable but for this to be a good question/answer you should edit them into something minimal which is compilable. As they stand, only you know what is going on and why/how it works.